# Swift closures - force a closure to always complete

Tags: swift, closures

Is it possible to force a closure to be completed?  In the same way that a function with a return value MUST always return, it would be ace if there was a way to force a closure to contain the syntax necessary to always complete.

For example, this code **will not compile** because the function does not always return a value:

```
func isTheEarthFlat(withUserIQ userIQ: Int) -> Bool {
    if userIQ > 10 {
        return false
    }
}
```

In the exact same way, I would like to define a function with a closure, **which will also not compile** if the closure never returns.  For example, the code below might never return a completionHandler:

```
func isTheEarthFlat(withUserIQ userIQ: Int, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if userIQ > 10 {
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```

The code above compiles, but I was wondering if there is a keyword which enforces that the closure sends a completion handler in all cases.  Maybe it has something to do with the `Void` in the above function?

Comment: Not a language level, though I have an interesting idea of how it could be achieve. Let me try some stuff

Comment: Can't you just call the completion handler at the very end of the method?

Comment: @Sweeper Most of our completion handlers are used for server access, so they will return (1) any error that occured and (2) the data from the server.  Since a server error is not the same error we want to show the user, we often have lots of functionality which decide what the error is, and equally we may want to manipulate the data returned from the server in a specific way.  All I'm asking is for the compiler to ensure that the completion handler is called in all branches of the code - exactly the same as the way a return value must be returned in a normal function.

Comment: "All I'm asking is for the compiler to ensure that the completion handler is called in all branches of the code - exactly the same as the way a return value must be returned in a normal function." You can't get the compiler to help you, but from a programmer point of view, the `defer` statement does what you want.

Comment: [SE-0073](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0073-noescape-once.md) would have given you this, however it was rejected on naming grounds (it was proposed as an extension of `@noescape`, which is now deprecated) as well as the underlying implementation requiring significant work. Hopefully though it's a feature that'll make its way into a future version of the language.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no language construct that will result in a compiler error if you forget (or don't need) to call the completion handler under all possible conditions like a `return` statement.

It's an interesting idea that might make a useful enhancement to the language. Maybe as a `required` keyword somewhere in the parameter declaration.

Answer (score 2):

There is no special keyword for what you want. But there is an interesting approach you can take into consideration, that won't compile:

```
func isTheEarthFlat(withUserIQ userIQ: Int, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    let result: Bool
    defer {
       completionHandler(result)
    }
    if userIQ > 10 {
        result = false
    }
}
```

that will do and is `completionHandler` is forced to be called:

```
func isTheEarthFlat(withUserIQ userIQ: Int, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    let result: Bool
    defer {
       completionHandler(result)
    }
    if userIQ > 10 {
        result = false
    } else {
        result = true
    }
}
```

Not sure it's a good pattern to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting technique I thought of. You define `GuarenteedExecution` and `GuarenteedExecutionResult` types.

A `GuarenteedExecution` is a wrapper around a closure, which is to be used in a context where the execution of the closure must be guaranteed.

The `GuarenteedExecutionResult` is the result of executing a `GuarenteedExecution`. The trick is to have a desired function, e.g. `isTheEarthFlat`, return a `GuarenteedExecutionResult`. The only way to obtain a `GuarenteedExecutionResult` instance is by calling `execute(argument:)` on a `GuarenteedExecution`. Effectively, the type checker features responsible for guaranteeing a return, are now being used to guarantee the execution of `GuarenteedExecution`.

```
struct GuarenteedExecutionResult<R> {
    let result: R

    fileprivate init(result: R) { self.result = result }
}

struct GuarenteedExecution<A, R> {
    typealias Closure = (A) -> R

    let closure: Closure

    init(ofClosure closure: @escaping Closure) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    func execute(argument: A) -> GuarenteedExecutionResult<R> {
        let result = closure(argument)
        return GuarenteedExecutionResult(result: result)
    }
}
```

Example usage, in a *seperate* file (so as to not have access to `GuarenteedExecutionResult.init`):

```
let guarenteedExecutionClosure = GuarenteedExecution(ofClosure: {
    print("This must be called!")
})

func doSomething(guarenteedCallback: GuarenteedExecution<(), ()>)
    -> GuarenteedExecutionResult<()> {
    print("Did something")
    return guarenteedCallback.execute(argument: ())
}

_ = doSomething(guarenteedCallback: guarenteedExecutionClosure)
```

Comment: Interesting idea, the only issue with this is you would have to define a different `GuaranteedExecution` for every number of parameters you would want. e.g. what if the closure is of type `(A, B) -> R`, `(A, B, C) -> R`, etc.

Comment: @Paolo Yeah, but you could just use a tuple instead. A `((X, Y, Z)) -> R)` matches a `(A) -> R`, where A is `(X, Y, Z)`